# Value does not fall within the expected range in a Windows Store app

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

My xaml codes it this:

```
<Page
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="wCommander.OrderListing"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:wCommander"
    xmlns:common="using:wCommander.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"><Page.Resources>
    <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
    <x:String x:Key="AppName">Order Lists</x:String>

    <Style x:Key="ContactGroups" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>

    </Page.Resources>

<!--
        This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
        * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
        * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
    -->
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#009DC6">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Margin="39,30,39,0" Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                        Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                        AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" 
                        IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,30,15" FontSize="36"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1"  Background="#FFFFFF">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="ORDER ID" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="#FF58B3D2"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CUSTOMER NAME" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="#FF58B3D2"/>
        <TextBlock Text="ORDER DATE" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="#FF58B3D2"/>
        <TextBlock Text="ORDER TOTAL" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="3" Foreground="#FF58B3D2"/>
        <TextBlock Text="STATUS" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="4" Foreground="#FF58B3D2"/>
        <TextBlock Text="ACTIONS" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="5" Foreground="#FF58B3D2"/>

    </Grid>





        <ListView x:Name="OrderListView"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContactGroups}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFFFFF" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="index_selected" >

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="25,0,25,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Foreground="#636D6F" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding customerName}" Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Foreground="#636D6F" Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding shippingCost}" Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="25,0,25,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Foreground="#636D6F" Grid.Column="2"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding totalSurcharge}" Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Foreground="#009DC6" Grid.Column="3"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding orderStatus}" Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="25,0,25,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Foreground="#636D6F" Grid.Column="4"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding paymentStatus}" Height="auto" Width="auto" Margin="0,0,25,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Foreground="#636D6F" Grid.Column="5"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I am loading JSON data the web with this code:

```
public OrderListing()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
    this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
    this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;
    loadData1();
}

private async void loadData1()
{
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();

    var response = await http.GetStringAsync("http://10.0.40.117/" + "rest/admin/order/list.json");

    var orderData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderRootClass>(response);

    OrderListView.ItemsSource = orderData;
}
```

This is order root class:

```
public class OrderRootClass
{
    public Order[] orders { get; set; }

}
```

It gives error. I found some post regarding this but this does not help.

Comment: What is the full error? Can you paste the error message and call stack? Also, where is the error occurring? What line? Is it a problem with the XAML, or the C#?

Comment: @MikeEason > It gives that error in the last line of loadData1 method. There is no more error information.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the OrderRootClass code, too. It should implement a collection of objects that expose the source properties of the bindings in your ItemTemplate.

Comment: @Clemens - sure I will. As soon as I wake up in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ItemsSource property should be assigned the orders collection, not the OrderRootClass instance.

```
var orderData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrderRootClass>(response);

OrderListView.ItemsSource = orderData.orders; // here
```

However, it should have given you a compiler error saying that orderData does not implement IEnumerable.